# How do I create and load a color profile with DisplayCal on Windows?

Tags: software, color-management

I have monitors that look different and I don't know how to make them look the same. So I buy a spider2 because it is cheap and I want to make sure it work before I spend a lot of money. The seller did not send me software, so I use displaycal. It work and make a lot of files. I try to add the ICC file in windows display settings but nothing change. Is the file made wrong or install wrong? I run the app again but it's still not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I always thought Windows was incapable of holding two ICC profiles simultaneously, without some 3rd party workaround. This from X-Rite would appear to support that, but may be out of date, I'm not sure - https://www.xrite.com/service-support/calibrating_and_profiling_dual_monitors_on_windows_platforms

Comment: Also - https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/65261/how-to-calibrate-2-monitors-identically and https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/98367/if-i-have-two-calibrated-monitors-will-photoshop-pick-the-right-monitor-profile

Comment: Doesn't color correction on Windows require specific application support? So the window decorations and desktop won't change, but the display of photos in Windows photo viewer and other programs should.

Comment: Even when properly profiled, two different monitors will not always look exactly the same if one is capable of displaying colors (within the designated color space) that the other is not capable of displaying. For instance, if one of your monitors can display 100% of the colors within sRGB, but the other one can only display 92% of sRGB, then the 8% of sRGB colors the second monitor can not display will be properly displayed on the first monitor, but will not be properly displayed on the second. Even if both monitors can show 92% of sRGB, the colors each can show may not be the exact same 92%.

Answer (score 1):

Use the profile loader that comes with DisplayCAL for loading profiles.

Some software (e.g. f.lux) may interefere with DisplayCAL's profile loader.

Otherwise, DisplayCAL's profile loader doing an excellent job.

Comment: I tried this. It didn't help. Will try again.